# Wordpress ACF - How to show additional information in a field type 'user' dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created a custom field using advance custom field plugin, and I selected in field type "user", which actually is a dropdown containing all of the users. I then added this field to a custom post.

All users have a unique 4 digit number in their profiles.

My client wants that, instead of having the users displayed in this dropdown when creating a new post, he wants to have the name AND this 4 digit number that each user has in its profile.

Is there a way to modify the "user" field type to have it show additional information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to filter [the results on the dropdown](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/advanced-custom-fields/tags/4.3.7/core/fields/user.php#L143). There are 3 filters available but only to modify the arguments to [`get_users()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users).

What is possible is to [create your own field type](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-a-new-field-type/). Use the file `advanced-custom-fields/core/fields/user.php` as template to create your custom users field.